# project euler 454 diophantine recipricols

Tags: python, diophantine

The question is:
In the following equation x, y, and n are positive integers.

1/x + 1/y = 1/n

For a limit L we define F(L) as the number of solutions which satisfy x < y ≤ L.

We can verify that F(15) = 4 and F(1000) = 1069.
Find F(1012).

I decided to test if I could find F(15)

```
count = 0
limit = 15
storage = []
x = 1
y = 1

for x in range(limit + 1):
    for y in range(limit + 1):
        x += 1
        y += 1
        n = x*y/(x+y)
        condition = x*y%(x+y)

        if (condition == 0 and x<y and y<limit):
            count += 1
            storage.append(x)
            storage.append(y)
            storage.append(n)

print (storage)
print (count)
```

But nothing is stored in the list.

Comment: Why do you increment `x` and `y` within the loop?

Comment: at hahahakebab that's sorta what a for loop does...

Comment: oh god sorry I got mixed up but now I get an error that says i'm dividing by zero

Comment: range(n) creates a list from `0` to `n-1`, eg. `range(3) == [0,1,2]`

Comment: @hahahakebab: Check out what `range(1, limit + 1)` can do for you. Also, the range for the inner loop should depend on `x`, this saves some iterations.

Comment: ahh yes thank you I can get solutions for F(15) and f(1000) now but F(10**12) takes too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying `x` inside the `y` loop. The `x += 1` belongs before the `y` loop.
You could eliminate the increment altogether by using `range()` effectively. `range(1,limit+1)` will start at 1.

You are also not comparing `y` and `limit` correctly. `y <= limit`.

A slightly modified version of your program:

```
count = 0
limit = 15
storage = []
x = 1
y = 1

for x in range(1,limit + 1):
    for y in range(1,limit + 1):
        n = x*y/(x+y)
        condition = x*y%(x+y)

        if (condition == 0 and x<y and y<=limit):
            count += 1
            storage.append(x)
            storage.append(y)
            storage.append(n)

print (storage)
print (count)
```

Comment: So then how can I use this to find the answer when the limit is 10**12

Comment: The Euler problems usually want a certain amount of analysis to limit the search space. Even after code optimizations to speed up your program (start y at x+1, don't calculate n, only update count not do the list append), this algorithm will take quintillions of centuries to complete in Python (on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

Even trying to calculate this at 10^5, you'll have one hell of a time with a brute force approach.  I've been trying to figure this one out too.

Here's what I know:

1/x + 1/y = 1/n can be rewritten as

1/(n+a) + 1/(n+b) = 1/n
This can be reduced to ab = n^2

(which is the method I used to solve for problems 108 and 110)
By getting all of the divisors of n^2 you can solve for 'a' and 'b', but that only really helps if n is a fixed integer.

I have not figured out how this will help me with 454 yet.

Comment: hmmmm would you mind keeping me posted if you find a solution?